# What highchart properties do I need to look at to fix blur of first chart?

Tags: typescript, highcharts

When I navigate to the forecasted data for the line chart, the bar chart blurs and will stay that way until I navigate off the line chart. This is not the intended behavior. Where should I look to fix this issue? The one thing I did notice is that the line chart has forecasted data while the bar chart does not. Could that be the reason why it isn't working properly?
[image: Blurred interface]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a default behaviour for inactive series. You can change it via setting opacity as follows:

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      states: {
        inactive: {
          opacity: 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2dpcjz7y/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.states.inactive.opacity

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the bug but I can share some sample data and the chart config that is being used. This is the same data from the chart listed above. This is the best I can do and if it doesn't help, I apologize. I can not share further. https://jsfiddle.net/ashman330/untchepz/2/

Comment: Thank you for providing more information. As I can notice, you used that settings for the spline series - `plotOptions.spline` . Try out to put it in the `plotOptions. series` .

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was looking for. Just need to check if this breaks anything else since these were global options.

Comment: You're welcome! Alternatively you can just put it in both `plotOptions.spline` and `plotOptions.column` (generally in those series which you don't want to make faded)